# Отображение функций

Tags: математика

Доброго времени суток!

Прошу, помогите в одном вопросе, ващпе ничего не понятно.

> Имеем два множества `S={b,c,e,i}` и `T={c,e,f,i}`, они входят в универсальное множество `U={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}`. Задать функцию из `S` в `T`: инъективную, сюръективую, биективную.

Как я понимаю, между множествами `S` и `T` нету функциональной зависимости и задать отображение не удастся (ведь нету соответствия между элементами обоих множеств) или же я ошибаюсь и зависимость вообще не нужна?

**Заранее спасибо!**

Comment: хммм, теперь меня терзают смутные сомнения. почему отображение именно функций, если по условию природа объектов множеств ни на что не влияет...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Инъекция - любое отображение, определяющее разным элементам разные значения. Сюръекция - отображение f из S в T, образ которого есть всё множество T, то есть у любого элемента из T есть прообраз.

Так как множества равномощны, то Вам удастся построить только биекцию из S в T, а не просто сюръекцию или инъекцию.

Пример:

```
b->c
c->e
e->f
i->i
```

Это и сюръекция, и инъекция и биекция.

P.S. А зачем здесь универсальное множество, я не понял.